# How to bind a part of a variable already binded

Tags: angularjs, binding

I have a loop ng-repeat that displays sevral icons.

```
 <div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-repeat="record in newlayout.display" align="center">
                <a class="btn btn-app" ng-href="#newlayout/{{newlayout.url}}{{newlayout.itemValue}}" >
                    <span class="badge bg-yellow" style="font-size:22px;">{{record.numberOfSamples}}</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-{{newlayout.labStyle}}"></i> {{record.lab}}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the second part of the binded variable **itemValue** should be dynamic

In my Js, I have this

```
    newLayout.url = 'sublabs/?labName=';
    newLayout.itemValue = 'record.lab';
```

The URL is dynamic.
When  I click on the first displayed Icon, the url should look like this :

But it didn't work as I had a compilation error..

Does someone have an idea how to fix this:

```
http://localhost:8181/#/newlayout/sublabs?labName=PIA/C1 - Shiftlabo
```

Where the record value "PIA/C1 - Shiftlabo" change.

So basically here if I change

```
 <a class="btn btn-app" ng-href="#newlayout/{{newlayout.url}}{{newlayout.itemValue}}" >
```

`{{newlayout.itemValue}}` by `{{record.lab}}` it would work..but the `{{record.**lab**}}` should be dynamic as it will have another value when I click on the icon. It will change to `{{record.subLab}}`

Thanks

Comment: what is the compilation error?

Comment: Hi  Jonnysai . The compilation is shown by intelli "jError: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error
Syntax Error: Token '{' is not a valid at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Comment: can you post an example of record

Comment: "second part of the binded variable itemValue should be dynamic" i was unable to understand may be post your record and ng-repeat

Comment: LLai,  Jonnysai I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [property acccessor bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) inside the binding:

```
 <div>{{record[labOrSublab]}}</div>
```

JS

```
var isSublab = false;
$scope.labOrSublab = "lab";

$scope.clickHandler = function() {
    isSublab = !isSublab;
    $scope.labOrSublab = isSublab ? 'subLab' : 'lab';
};
```